# "Failed to load session "ubuntu"" problem

Tags: notification, session

I run **Ubuntu 12.04**. After installation **I have disabled guest account**, removed error notification, gave myself super user rights.
I made some applications in `/usr/applications` **useable only for me**, **created standard user account**.

Then I pressed restart in shut down menu, **but system just logged off**. **After rebooting by Terminal** there was **"Failed to load "ubuntu"" notification**.

I don't know if it was my fault, but really have to fix that problem. By the way, I have no internet access for that PC. Hope you will help me!

Comment: maybe you can add some info from your log in `/var/log/syslog` that could help us to help you. but looks like permissons to me.

Comment: After little experiment I have noticed, that this happens after I give none permission for other users to use all programs in /usr/share/applications